# Inno Setup: Load file edited during installation for wpInfoAfter

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to use `wpInfoAfter` page in my installation to display a summary of my installation with Inno Setup. And I would like to load a file that is edited during the `[Run]` section and during the `ssInstall` step.

In the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_infoafterfile) they say that is should be located to be loaded by the compiler, and me I would like to load it after install.

How can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dummy file for the `InfoAfterFile` directive (just to activate the page).

And then on runtime, load the file you want:

```pascal
WizardForm.InfoAfterMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile(FileName);
```